# Prairiefire Crabapple leaves drying and falling off

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, leaves, crabapples

I recently planted two Prairiefire Crabapples in my backyard. One of them is currently doing well, while the other one, not so much. I see leaf-scorch in all the leaves and they are falling off.

[image]

It does not seem like any disease. Both the Crabapples are receiving equal amounts of water and sunshine. Any idea what might be going on? I do not see any new leaves sprouting either. How do I help the tree?

Comment: Ymmm this looks complicated. In you shoes I would throw the plant and it's roots in the garbage and hope for the best.